# Condition under which a locally convex topological vector space becomes a normed linear space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Is this true that a locally convex topological (Hausdorff) vector space becomes a normed space when its local base has only one element, so only one Minkowski functional and so only one seminorm and hence norm.

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

This result was proved in 1935 by A. Kolmogoroff: The topology of a locally convex topological vector space is generated by a norm iff there exists a bounded neighborhood of $0$.